# How do I call an outside method within a callback object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to implement a way for customers to pay online through my company's website, but I'm having troubles being able to call other methods that are outside the `callback` object.  Here is a snippet of the code that I'm trying to execute and having issues with:

```
OpenLightBox(txn_type, invoices, amount, customer){

        $.get('/token_req', 
            {
                amount: amount, 
                invoice: `#9999999`, 
                type: txn_type == "cc" ? "ccsale" : "ecspurchase",
                email: customer.Email,

            }, (response) => {
        
            let token = response;

            let paymentFields = {
                ssl_txn_auth_token: token
            }

            let callback = {
                onError: (error) => {
                    console.error(error);   // api/payment_error
                },
                onDeclined: (response) => {
                    console.error(response.ssl_result_message); // api/payment_decline
                },
                onApproval: (response) => {
                    this.PayInvoices(response, invoices); // error this.PayInvoices is not defined
                }
            };
            
            PayWithConverge.open(paymentFields, callback);

            
        })
    }

    PayInvoices(response, invoices){
        console.log({invoices});
        console.log({response});
    }

    FormatDate2(dateIn){
       let [month,day,year] = dateIn.split('/');
       return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    }
```

`PayWithConverge` is a method that comes from an asynchronous script inside my `index.html` file.

The issue occurs when I have a successful transaction and when I try to call my `PayInvoices` method.
I tried using `.bind(this);` on just about everything that I could think of but still run into the same issue.

I want to know if it's possible to call methods that are outside this callback object, and if so, how could I do that given the code I have here?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

The `OpenLightBox` method is being called like this within my code:

```
<div className="ad-size-container fade-in">
                    <div className="page-header">
                        <h1>Pay Invoice</h1>
                    </div>
                    <Invoice invoices={this.state.Invoices} customer={this.state.Customer} getToken={this.OpenLightBox}></Invoice>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please show us how you call `OpenLightBox` (as that call determines the value of `this` in your arrow functions).

Comment: Are all of these functions part of a Class or part of an Object?

Comment: @RossAllen these functions are all part of a React class.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated my question to show how it is being called.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Unfortunately no, this was one of the first SO questions I looked at to solve this issue.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. *That's* the place where you need to use `bind` or an arrow function, i.e. `<Invoice … getToken={this.OpenLightBox.bind(this)}></Invoice>`/`<Invoice … getToken={(...args) => this.OpenLightBox(...args)}></Invoice>`. (Or put the `bind` in the constructor of your class)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! I will give this a try.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! This way worked.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

It is because `this` refers to the Object inside `get` function.

Move it outside, above `$.get`

```
OpenLightBox(txn_type, invoices, amount, customer){

        let callback = {
            onError: (error) => {
                console.error(error); 
            },
            onDeclined: (response) => {
                console.error(response.ssl_result_message); 
            },
            onApproval: (response) => {
                this.PayInvoices(response, invoices); 
            }
        };
// .... rest of your code
```

Because arrow functions have lexical `this` binding.
You can also keep it where it is but use regular functions, i.e:

```
    let callback = {
        onApproval: function(response) {
            this.PayInvoices(response, invoices); 
        }
        // ... rest of code
    };
```

Comment: I think using regular functions is the opposite of what is intended. The OP used arrow functions, with the intention that `this` should refer to their own `PayInvoices` method. The way you propose it, it is quite certain that `this` will not refer to their class anymore. Moreover, *"the Object inside get function"* is not clear... Certainly the callback passed to `$.get` is not defining another `this`, as this callback is an arrow function...

Comment: Okay, I see, second way would not work, but first one should work (moving it outside `$.get`?

Comment: If it does not work inside `$.get` callback, it will not work outside it either, since there the value of `this` is exactly the same. The key is what Bergi wrote in comments...